# Coalgebras of a free-forgetful adjunction

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, adjoint-functors, monads

An **algebra** for a monad $T : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ is an arrow $m : Tc \to c$
satisfying some relevant conditions regarding the unit $\eta : 1 \Rightarrow T$ and the multiplication $\mu : T^2 \Rightarrow T$. For the free-forgetful adjunction of groups, $F \dashv U$, we get a monad $T = UF : \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$, and the algebras of this monad are exactly the groups.

We can dualize this and look at the comonad $FU : \mathsf{Grp} \to \mathsf{Grp}$.
Coalgebras for this comonad are group homomorphisms $w : G \to FUG$ with conditions dual to those we placed on algebras.
Most notably, we require the composite $G \overset{w}{\to} FUG \overset{\epsilon_G}{\to} G$ be the identity, so (unless I'm making a silly mistake) we are forced to let $w$ be the obvious inclusion of $G$ into $FUG$ (which is a homomorphism precisely when $G$ is free).

I can't find any discussions of the comonad associated to a free-forgetful adjunction, despite them being a go-to example of adjunctions in general. Moreover, all of the examples I *can* find regarding coalgebras are somehow infinitary in nature. E.g. coalgebras for the stream monad are exactly forward orbits of a dynamical system. Is there anything interesting to say about coalgebras of a free-forgetful adjunction? My previous paragraph seems to indicate "no", but I would love to be pleasantly surprised.

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: It sometimes happens that an adjunction is simultaneously monadic and comonadic. When this happens you essentially have a way of recognising when an algebra is a free algebra.

Comment: I don't agree with your conclusion about $w$, in fact the "obvious inclusion" is never a group morphism (the obvious inclusion sends $e$ to the word with one letter which is $e$, which is *not* the neutral element of $FUG$). However, $\epsilon_G\circ w = id_G$ forces $w$ to be injective, which thus forces $G$ to be free. Conversely, if $G$ is free, it can be made into a coalgebra - we end up with what Zhen Lin points out just above

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit tired when I posted this. Obviously the inclusion $w$ forces $G$ to be free

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect this

Comment: @ZhenLin - to make sure I understand, you're saying that the coalgebras of $FU$ are exactly the free objects? At least in the situation where the dualized Eilenberg-Moore category is equivalent to $\mathsf{Set}$?

Comment: Not quite. In the situation where you have a monadic–comonadic adjunction, the free algebras admit the structure of a coalgebra, and the category of coalgebras is equivalent to the "base" category. This rarely happens for categories monadic over $\textbf{Set}$, however.

Answer (score 1):

The coalgebras for the comonad generated by a monadic adjunction are studied in Jacobs's paper [Bases as Coalgebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0844), whose thesis is that coalgebras may be seen as *bases* in a suitable sense, generalising bases of vector spaces when the monad in question is the free vector space monad on $\mathbf{Set}$. This is part of the more general story of [nuclear adjunctions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nuclear+adjunction).